# Add Tapped Command event to a image in a gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, events, gridview, command

I tried everything but I can't fire the command on my images in the gridview.. Did I forget something?

As you can see it's a gridview that display's a few images horizontaly, but I want if you tap on one you go to a detailscreen where you can zoom the image..

XAML Code:

```
 <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedActivity.ObjectAttachments}"
                              Margin="10,0,0,0"
                              IsHitTestVisible="False"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Height="200">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding AttachmentImageSource}"
                                       Width="150"
                                       Height="150"
                                       Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                       Margin="0,10,10,0">
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </GridView>
```

C# code behind:

```
 public RelayCommand TappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand( () =>
           {
               MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Message Box is displayed");

                msgbox.ShowAsync();
                //do stuff when it works
           });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set IsHitTestVisible="True". False disables user interaction on that control.

Comment: Indeed that's it, and how do I pass "AttachmentImageSource" the value of the Image to my ViewModel?